# Public dynamic array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to set public dynamic array like this:

```
Public BenData(1 To Worksheets("Database").Range("A9").End(xlDown).Row, 1 To 4)
```

But VBA doesn't allow that. Is there any way around?

Comment: IIRC You need `Redim` whenever the bounds of the array are not constant. Specifically: `Public BenData() As Variant : Redim BenData(1 To Worksheets("Database").Range("A9").End(xlDown).Row, 1 To 4)`

Comment: you need to declare it as `Public`, and later `Redim` it (like you have)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with whether or not the variable is public or private - VBA requires that ***any*** variable declaration is a constant expression.  This is actually why the `ReDim` statement exists - a normal `Dim foo(10) As Bar` expression will create a memory allocation at *compile time*.  Outside of using API calls, `ReDim` is the only way to allocate memory at run time. As mentioned in the comments, if you really need a global dynamic array you need to initialize it at runtime:

```
Public BenData() As Variant

Sub UseBenData()
    ReDim BenData(1 To Worksheets("Database").Range("A9").End(xlDown).Row, 1 To 4)
    '...

End Sub
```